# What steps are needed to create a new iOS language without jailbreaking

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've a burning desire to create a new iOS language called "English(pirate)", in honor of International Speak Like A Pirate day.

The reason be simple, the FaceBook app looks at Settings->General->International->Language to decide how to localize.  That scurvy Zuckerburg be ignorin' me options that I gave on his site.

Since just the language name is enough to trigger the FaceBook app to use pirate localization, I was thinking that I could just copy-and-rename English(US) to be English(pirate).  But though I be a slashing outlaw programmer, I'll not void my warranty for such trivia, so no jailbreakin.

Be there an Apple Approved manner to create a new language on their iOS platform?  A keg o' rum and a saucy wench to the best answer!  (Or a small bounty if the TOC don't allow rum and wenches...)

Comment: Sorry dude no official way. Not a very good pirate if you're not willing to jailbreak your phone now are ye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Apple approved way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html

If you choose to create a new designator, be sure to follow the rules found in sections 2.2.1 and 4.5 of [BCP 47: Tags for Identifying Languages](ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/bcp/bcp47.txt). Tags that do not follow these conventions are not guaranteed to work. When using subtags, ensure that the abbreviation stored by the user’s language settings matches the designator used by your .lproj directory exactly.